# How to perform operation on multiple values in lambda?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
In: df

                                      AAPL               IBM 
2016-04-27 00:00:00+00:00            98.113                NaN   
2016-04-28 00:00:00+00:00            97.288                NaN   
2016-04-29 00:00:00+00:00            94.147            145.932   
2016-05-02 00:00:00+00:00            93.511            145.595   
2016-05-03 00:00:00+00:00            95.161            143.515   
2016-05-04 00:00:00+00:00            95.320            143.614   
2016-05-05 00:00:00+00:00            94.070            145.892   
2016-05-06 00:00:00+00:00            93.450            147.970   
2016-05-09 00:00:00+00:00            93.770            148.200   
2016-05-10 00:00:00+00:00            93.570            150.040
```

I returned 2 max values from another dataframe(`bar`), those are:

```
In: max_values = bar.max()
In: max_values
Out: AAPL   111.710
     IBM    151.676
```

I want to get values, column name and if possible its index of that particular values whose resulting value is between 0.04 and 0.08. and store them in new dataframe. I tried this:

```
foo = df.apply((lambda s:(0.04 <=(1 - s.max() / max_values) <= 0.08)==True))
```

But getting error because `max_values` contains two values.

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index AAPL')
```

How do i perform operation on each values in `max_values` in `lambda`?

I want the output like this:

```
In: foo
Out: AAPL   93.511
     IBM    145.892
#this means 93.511 and 145.892 are the values, upon which performing percentage operation,
returned value which was between 0.04 and 0.08.
```

Comment: You might want `abs(1 - s.max() / max_values)`, no ? Otherwise it is not symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element-wise conditional expressions are a bit tricky with series. You have to put them in parentheses and add them one by one.
I am surprised by how short the solution is ; tell me if it fits your needs.

```
ratios = abs(1 - df / max_values)
mask = (0.04 <= ratios) & (ratios <= 0.08)
solution = df[mask.all(axis=1)]
```

`df / max_values` is a division column-wise and element-wise : every element of `df["AAPL"]` is divided by `max_values["AAPL"]`, the same for `"IBM"`.

`mask` shows for each value if the condition is true.

`solution` selects only the rows for which the condition is true in all values of the row.

Comment: Am new to python, can you please elaborate, and express how the output will look like using your solution? i just want the output as explained in my question, you have freedom to do any sort of operations, even without lambdas.

Comment: the best would be for you to try the code, and look at each step what are `ratios`, `mask`, and `solution` :)  
I'll explain more in detail, but `solution` should be what you want, if you want the rows for which the condition is verified for the two columns

Comment: For sure i will check, but am surprised looking at the size of solution :) and wondering whether the solution is complete or do you want more clarification regarding my question, if so feel free to ask.

Comment: I explained more ; what makes it so short is that all the operations are vectorized (done elements-wise, columns-wise or rows-wise) internally :)
this is true for the majority of the `pandas` methods

Comment: Thats great, i will try your solution tomorrow, since its dark night here, if you dont mind i will post you regarding the solution worked for me or not :)

Comment: Your solution Worked, Thanks a lot. However, `solution` returns `Empty Dataframe` maybe because `.all()` and some rows has both `True` and `False`. But atleast i got an headstart from your solution, thanks again.

Comment: If you want rows where AT LEAST ONE of the values (and not all) satisfy the conditions, replacing `mask.all(axis=1)` by `mask.any(axis=1)` should work :)